# Error 404 instead of 403 if a page is forbidden with Java EE 8 API security

Tags: security, java-ee-8

I use a @CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition to ask login and password to the users.
When users are not allowed to view a JSF page, they receive a 404 error code. Shouldn't it be a 403 error code?

Comment: How is this related to JSF? JSF has no knowledge of you using the Java EE 8 API

Comment: I don't know. My application use JSF and the problem happened for navigations to JSF pages, so I gave the context in case it would be a useful information.

Comment: Then narrow it down... Does the same happen with plain JSP's?  or even plain html files? Both not being processed by the JSF servlet... That is trouble shooting, debugging, develloping...

Comment: The same with an HTML page, so I remove JSF.

Comment: Cheers... Remember things like this for next questions: Narrow things down by eliminating (=creating a '[mcve])